# What exactly is Crystal Momentum, $\hbar k$?

Tags: momentum, solid-state-physics, semiconductor-physics, crystals, bloch-oscillation

The title says it all really.

Does this mean that the crystal is moving?

From my notes, I read that

> The effect of an external force on an electron in the crystal is to
> change the crystal momentum $\hbar k$. In the absence of a force, the crystal momentum must be constant
> and thus conserved.

> In a full band the net crystal momentum of electrons should be zero

> For an electric field, $\mathcal{E_x}$, we find a change in crystal momentum, $k_x$, $$\hbar\frac{dk_x}{dt}=q\mathcal{E_x}$$

> The missing ingredient, required to describe conduction,
> is scattering, which we assumed to be negligible. But
> where does the scattering come from? While the force
> of the electric field on electrons causes a change in
> crystal momentum, scattering must somehow restore
> the crystal momentum to their original values. Since
> Bloch oscillations are incredibly difficult to observe,
> electrons must be scattered before they can cross the
> FBZ boundary. The only other entities within the crystal
> with large crystal momentum are of course phonons.

---

*These quotes are not related* and quite honestly I have no idea what any of the quotes mean, as I don't know what is meant by 'crystal momentum'. If anyone wants to know the context from which those quotes came please let me know.

So, my question is as follows: In layman's terms (if possible), what is crystal momentum?

---

**N.B**

Before posting this question I looked at this [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/1725/is-crystal-momentum-really-momentum) and I'm finding it hard to understand. I'm only a 2nd year undergraduate, who has begun reading solid state.

Comment: Here are a few more questions about phonons & crystal momentum: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/240514/123208 & https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/280678/123208

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Crystal momentum arises when you consider the allowed energy eigenstates of the electrons which inhabit a crystal.  One finds that the allowed energies in crystals are not discrete (as they are for an isolated atom), but rather form continuous bands separated by gaps.

In the plot below, I've plotted the first band in blue and the second band in red; the dotted lines on the vertical axis show the continuous intervals of allowed energies which correspond to each band.

[image]
These states are labeled by two numbers, $n$ and $k$.  $n$ is the band index, which tells you what energy band the state lives in; $k$ (or $\hbar k$, I suppose) is the so-called *crystal momentum*, which tells you where (left to right) in that energy band you are. In the above diagram, I plotted two different possible states - $n=1$ and $k=-1$, and $n=2,k=0.7$.

You should not think of $\hbar k$ as the physical momentum of the crystal itself.  Rather, it is a kind of pseudo-momentum which labels the allowed electronic energy states.  Neither should you think of it as the genuine momentum of the particular energy eigenstate which it labels, for the simple reason that the energy eigenstates do not *have* definite momentum.

Despite not being the genuine momentum, $\hbar k$ has some momentum-like properties.  Applying an external force to the electrons in the system causes the crystal momentum  of a particular state to change according to
$$\frac{d}{dt}(\hbar \mathbf k) = \mathbf F_{ext}$$

Furthermore, if the electronic states interact with external particles (phonons, photons, etc), the sum of the crystal momentum of the electrons and *genuine* momentum of the external particles is conserved$^\dagger$.  This is important when analyzing how electrons can jump from one energy state to the other by interactions with such particles.

---

$^\dagger$Not quite conserved - rather, conserved up to a *reciprocal lattice vector*.  In other words, if $\mathbf k$ and $\mathbf k'$ are the crystal momenta before and after some event, then we say that $\mathbf k$ is conserved up to a reciprocal lattice vector if

$$\mathbf k'  -\mathbf k = \mathbf G$$
for some reciprocal lattice vector $\mathbf G$ (possibly the zero vector).

Comment: I'm not sure this could be considered a layman explanation. As a layman myself I'm still not really sure what crystal momentum is. I know it's been a long time since this answer was accepted, but if you could make the answer even simpler for someone like me that would be great!

Comment: @Connor It depends on what you mean by "layman." If you are not a student of physics, the best I can do is to say that when an electron travels through a crystal, its momentum is not conserved due to its interactions with the stationary ion lattice. However, there is a related quantity called *crystal momentum* which is more useful, and which is conserved in a slightly different sense.

Comment: @Connor If you *are* a student of physics who has some familiarity with quantum mechanics and the terminology of elementary solid state physics (lattice vectors, reciprocal lattice vectors, etc) and still find my answer difficult to understand, then I would be happy to clarify any specific points that are giving you trouble.

Comment: Thanks so much for responding so late after your answer. I have two questions: 1. What aspect of the electron's interaction with the ion lattice prevents its motion from being conserved? 2. Is crystal momentum related to phonons?

Comment: @Connor 1) From a semi-classical perspective, the electron experiences an electrostatic force from the ions, which means that its momentum will not be conserved.  Recall that $\frac{d}{dt}\mathbf p = \mathbf F$. 2) No, the description I gave assumes that the lattice is completely rigid and stationary. If we allow lattice vibrations, then the crystal momentum of the electrons will **not** be conserved. However, in a scattering event the sum of the crystal momentum of the electron and the (genuine) momentum of the phonon *will* be conserved, which is an example of why crystal momentum is useful.

Comment: 1) I assume the momentum of the ion and electron together will be conserved? 2) Is crystal momentum something to do with the bulk movement of electrons?

Comment: 1) In principle, yes. However, in practice we generally take the lattice to be infinitely large and absolutely stationary. In such a model, the lattice is not subject to Newton's laws and momentum is simply not a conserved quantity. This is similar to what we would do when modeling a basketball bouncing on the ground; in *principle* total momentum is conserved and the Earth recoils by some infinitesimal amount with each bounce, but in *practice* we don't account for this and simply say that momentum isn't conserved.  2) Not in any direct way I can think of. It's just an analogous [...]

Comment: [...] quantity to momentum which is useful inside a crystal.

Comment: 1) Okay great, that's cleared up for me then! 2) Okay, so if it's not vibrations in the lattice, like phonons, and it's not to do with the bulk movement of electrons, is it to do with the movement of single electrons? If so, why is the momentum associated with that movement conserved?

Comment: Hmmm re-reading your answer I think I may understand. Crystal momentum tells you the energy of an electron in a given band n. However, rather than call it band energy, it's called crystal momentum because external forces can change that part of electron's energy through means which are analagous to momentum change. Do I have it right?

Comment: The momentum *isn't* conserved, which is the point.  It is the *crystal momentum* which is conserved. Perhaps you'd prefer to call it *pseudomomentum* to make clear the fact that it is distinct from what we would ordinarily call momentum.  As for your second comment, the energy of a state can be expressed as a function of $k$ and $n$, but $k$ is not the energy. I really don't know how to explain it more clearly, so perhaps it would help to ask a separate question or take a look at some elementary solid state physics text to clarify the question.

Comment: @Connor I'm not sure if you ever received clarity on your question regarding what crystal momentum is, but, if it helps, I think of crystal momentum as being distinct from the classical/Newtonian momentum, in that crystal momentum cannot take on any value - it isn't continuous. This is because the energy of the corresponding electron cannot take on any value of energy; i.e., it is a discretized quantity. This affects the dispersion E(k) of the electron, discretizing its wavenumber k, and thereby discretizing its mometum (or *pseudomomentum*, here).

Comment: @chevestong I don't think that's the right way to think about it. For an infinite crystal, both the crystal momentum and energy of the electronic states are continuous. They are discrete for finite crystals in which we enforce periodic boundary conditions, but so is the canonical momentum in such cases.

Comment: @J.Murray ah, I see. It seems that I didn't really understand crystal momentum back when I first learned about it, then! From a comment over on reddit, I found something thart helped me differentiate the two: "I wanted to point out the difference between real electrons and quasiparticles. These quasiparticles are some sort of collective behavior of the entire electron system (and to some extend also the lattice). Imagine a stadium full of people, that performs a "La Ola" wave. The individual people correspond to the electrons, while the La Ola wave is the quasi-particle. [...]

Comment: [...] When we are talking about crystal electrons we are always talking about quasiparticles. These quasiparticles have a defined momentum, the crystal momentum. But indiviual electrons don't have a defined momentum. Just like the La Ola wave has a certain velocity, while the people doing the La Ola don't move from their seats.". I'm not sure if you agree with this analogy, @J.Murray, but it helped me wrap my head around the distinction. This was taken from https://www.reddit.com/r/AskPhysics/comments/akmodh/comment/ef9xcxd/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3

Comment: I had some trouble reconciling this answer to Marek's answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/1751/9416), but I think I'm understanding the concept of crystal momentum a little more clearly now. My attempt to reconcile @J.Murray's answer here to Marek's there: crystal momentum can be thought of as "real momentum" insofar as there being a change in the affected crystal lattice's momentum (via interactions with the atoms of the lattice and/or their electrons), while keeping in mind that electrons do not have a definite momentum due to them being made up of lots of different frequencies

Comment: @chevestong Here's a good exercise to help.  Can you give me a clear definition of "real momentum"? I don't mean a formula like $\mathbf p = m\mathbf v$ - I mean I want to know what information is encoded in the quantity $\mathbf p$, and why it's useful to talk about.